# How to check if a dictionary is invertible

Tags: python, dictionary, inverse

I am working on a question that requires to point out the problem in a function that determines whether a dictionary is invertible (for every value appearing in the dictionary, there is only one key that maps to that value) or not. The question is below:

```
def is_invertible(adict):
    inv_dict = make_inv_dict(adict)
    return adict == inv_dict

def make_inv_dict(adict):
    if len(adict) > 0:
       key, val = adict.popitem()
       adict = make_inv_dict(adict)
       if val not in adict.values():
          adict[key] = val
       return adict
    else:
        return {}
```

Currently, this returns `False` for `{'a': 'b', 'b': 'e', 'c': 'f'}` when it is supposed to be `True`. I am sure that there is an issue in `make_inv_dict` function; is it simply because `adict` is not an appropriate variable name in `adict = make_inv_dict(adict)`? Or is there another reason why the function returns a wrong outcome?

Comment: You can check if a dictionary is invertible simply with `len(set(adict.values())) == len(adict)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least three problems with the function you've given:

1. The condition `adict == inv_dict` checks whether the dictionary is *its own inverse*, not merely that it's invertible.
2. It uses `pop_item` to remove a key/value pair from the input dictionary, and then inserts it backwards, so the function operates in-place. By the time it's finished, `adict`'s original contents will be completely destroyed, so the comparison will be meaningless anyway.
3. The line `adict[key] = val` inserts the key/value pair in the original order; the inverse order should be `adict[val] = key`. So this function doesn't do what its name promises, which is to make an inverse dictionary.

It should be noted that if not for the destruction of the dictionary (2.), the mistakes (1.) and (3.) would cancel out, because the outcome of the function is to rebuild the original dictionary but without duplicate values.

---

I'm guessing some people will find this question if they're looking for a correct way to invert a dictionary, so here is one: this function returns the inverse dictionary if it's possible, or `None` otherwise.

```py
def invert_dict(d):
    out = dict()
    for k,v in dict.items():
        if v in out:
            return None
        out[v] = k
    return out
```

Helper function returning a boolean for whether a dictionary is invertible:

```py
def is_invertible(d):
    return invert_dict(d) is not None
```

Answer (score 1):

My Answer:

```
def is_invertible(dict_var):
    return len(dict_var.values()) == len(set(dict_var.values()))
```

Comment: No need to convert the set into a list before you do `len` - it works perfectly well (and faster) to write `len(set(...))`.